# Deploy Local Docker Image with Kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have a single node Kubeadm deployment, I want do be able to run docker images the same way that you can in Minikube with eval $(minikube docker-env), is this possible?

I know that I can side-load a tarball and start a docker image to host my images, but I don't want that. Also, it seems that it would be most helpful to find out how to find the environment variables related to any program, not just this one. I will be looking into that but figured I would ask in case someone knew right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the docker image containing kubeadm binary, you can find it on docker hub [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/kindest/node/tags) (e.g for Kubernetes v1.14.0 - use 'kindest/node:v1.14.0')

If you want to re-use node's docker-engine, please follow one of many online tutorials on how to 'connect docker client to a remote docker daemon'. e.g [this](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-73-connecting-to-a-remote-docker-daemon) one. If you want to have a similar experience like with 'minikube docker-env', install standalone docker-machine tool, and follow instruction from [this](https://www.kevinkuszyk.com/2016/11/28/connect-your-docker-client-to-a-remote-docker-host/) guide.